# Android thread not running continiously

Tags: android, multithreading

When I run the below code, the seconds do not increment. But if I simply do startTimer.run() then the seconds increment.

```
StartTimer startTimer = new StartTimer();
int numProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numProcessors);
executorService.submit(startTimer);
...
...

 private class StartTimer implements Runnable {
        //    Runnable StartTimer = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (running) {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat =
                        new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
                final String strDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
                helloWorldTextView.setText(strDate);
                helloWorldTextView.postDelayed(this, 500);
            }
        };
    }
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does an executer service start a runnable? Don't you have to use a thread? Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is expected. You initiliaze your Runnable first and then you run it by calling the run() method.